# Setting x-axis in ggplot to end at the last date data is available for

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I have a line graph with the number of visitors staying at a campsite per night.  My dataset ends at 10-28-2019, but my graph extends past that date which is unnecessary and provides false information.  I want the graph to end at max(nightcounts$date) but am not sure where this should properly go.  I tried adding it in line 1 as

```
aes(max(nightcounts$date), nightcounts$Freq
```

as an addition to the current aesthetic.  Secondly, I am tryin got reformat the x- axis labeling to have the number day below each point, and then the month as a second line below thse points such as

27  28  29  30  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15

September___________October

```
1 base <- ggplot(data=nightcounts, aes(nightcounts$date, nightcounts$Freq)) #using ggplot with x = date, y = counts
2 base + geom_line(col="darkorchid4", aes(group = 1)) + #calling geom_line to make a line connecting data points
3  geom_point() + #calling geom_point to add points for each data point
4  labs(title = "Number of Visitors Camping per Night", #adding labels
5       x = "Date",
6       y = "Visitors") +
7  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m-%d-%Y"), breaks = date_breaks("week")) +
8  ggsave("Camping by Date.png") #save the image
```

[image of my current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgn7G.png)

Comment: Add `expand = c(0, 0)` inside `scale_x_date` to keep the axis from expanding beyond the data. To label the day of month use `date_format("%d")`. Getting month labels is a little trickier, I can maybe find a dupe for that too.

Comment: Also, don't use `data$column` inside `aes()`, just use column names. `aes(date, Freq)`. If you use some more complicated features like facets or aggregates, `data$column` will cause problems.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I changed the aesthetic coding.  The ```expand = c(0, 0)``` did not change the graph and is still including extra dates. Edit: it was an error in the original dataset I just found, thank you!!